# Does it matter which order I use for my CSS border-top values?

Tags: css

When I see the `border-top` property used by different authors, they all say to use it a different way.

For example, at http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_border-top.asp it is defined in this order:

```
width style color
```

If I define in another way, like `color` or `style` first, will I get problems?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm assuming you are asking what the problems could be if you don't use the correct order of properties when using a `border` shorthand tag. Additionally you seem to be thrown of by different definitions of the order of properties.

I'll just be quoting the [W3 CSS reference for border shorthands](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#border-shorthand-properties) here:

```
'border'
    Value:      [ <border-width> || <border-style> || <'border-top-color'> ]
```

<strike>So the **only** correct way to use `border-top` shorthand is to 1. set the width, 2. style, 3. color.</strike> *incorrect*

As pointed out by Paul, the double bar "||" means that the properties **can appear in any order**,  so usually browsers don't have a problem no matter what order you throw at them.

However: I usually see definitions in the form of `border-top: 1px solid red;` - but that might just be "best practice" but doesn't matter in the end.

Comment: Incorrect. See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/about.html#value-defs — “A double bar (||) separates two or more options: one or more of them must occur, in any order”.

Answer (score 6):

As [moontear mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077421/does-it-matter-which-order-i-use-for-my-css-border-top-values/4077517#4077517), the CSS 2 spec defines `border-top`’s accepted values like this:

```
[ <border-width> || <border-style> || <'border-top-color'> ] | inherit
```

The double bars mean than width, style and colour may be used in any order. So according to the spec, you shouldn’t get any problems if you use them in a different order.

I’ve never personally seen browsers have any issues with different orders for this property.

Comment: Paul, this is not how I thought StackOverflow works. Usually you would comment on the wrong post and let the author have a chance to correct it - which I just did. You downvoted the original answer, left a comment and made your own answer which is just a copy of mine... weird behavior. I upvoted your comment on my question because it raises a valid point.

Comment: @moontear — sorry, fair enough, it’s just you got it exactly backwards. I don’t think it’s a good idea to encourage people to write answers that they’re not sure about. Well done for correcting it though, downvote rescinded.

Comment: Well I was sure, as I always used to write the values in that order. It's new to me that they can be written in any order (I though it was similar to border: [top] [right] [bottom] [left]. But that's what I like this site for too: to learn new things ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You usually won't get a problem: All browsers that I know will interpret your input as best as possible, even if it is not in the correct order.

That said, *do* stick with the official order. It will avoid problems with other, less lenient clients, parsers, and such.

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans IDE 8+ only shows the color picker if you use this format:

```
Border: red 1px solid;
```

Anyone knows how to change the order to:

```
Border: 1px solid red;
```