# Is there a correct order to declaring border-width and border-style?

Tags: html, css

I'm looking over the page for [`border-width`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-width.asp) on w3schools and it says that:

> **Note:** Always declare the border-style property before the border-width property. An element must have borders before you can set the width.

I'm trying to find a reference corroborates this statement. It seems like declaring the `border-width` before the `border-style` works just fine.

```css
.demo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
.ten-red-solid {
  border-width: 10px;
  border-color: red;
  border-style: solid;
}
.red {
  border-color: red;
}
.ten {
  border-width: 10px;
}
.solid {
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="ten-red-solid demo"></div>
<div class="ten red solid demo"></div>
```

Comment: Hmm, I've been using the `border: xpx solid color` shorthand since the beginning of time and have never came across any glitches - outdated note maybe?

Comment: I did a search and found this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077421/does-it-matter-which-order-i-use-for-my-css-border-top-values) saying that the order of the properties with double bars in shorthand tags don't matter. I was wondering about this note specifically because I couldn't find anything else claiming order of declaring these two styles mattered.

Comment: Hmmm. One more reason to not use w3schools.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't true.

W3Schools aren't an official documentation source and therefore any advice shouldn't be taken too seriously.

> W3Schools is optimized for learning, testing, and training. Examples
>   might be simplified to improve reading and basic understanding.
>   Tutorials, references, and examples are constantly reviewed to avoid
>   errors, **but we cannot warrant full correctness of all content**.

Browsers evaluate styles once all of them have been loaded, irrespective of the order in which they are declared.

For clarity the following 2 styles are identical:

```
div{
   border-width:2px;
   border-style:solid;
   border-color:#000;
}

div{
   border-style:solid;
   border-width:2px;
   border-color:#000;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming my suspicions.

Answer (score 1):

An element certainly can have a `border-width` value without a `border-style` (or rather, with a `border-style` that defaults to `none`). You just won't see the border.

I suspect what W3Schools *really* means to say is that you should make sure you always declare `border-style` when giving an element a border, since, given its default, you will not see a border no matter what border width and color you give an element if you forget to give it a border style.<sup>1</sup>

Or if the author of that page really does believe that the order of declarations matters, then the author is mistaken. The `border` shorthand can accept values in any order provided they correspond to one of each of `border-color`, `border-style` and `border-width`, since there are no lexical ambiguities between values for any of the component properties (i.e. a value for `border-color` will never be mistaken for a value of the other two properties).

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>On the other hand, declaring just `border-style` alone is enough for an element to generate a border. This is because the initial value of `border-width` is actually `medium`, not zero, and the initial value of `border-color` is `currentColor`, not `transparent`.</sub>

```css
div {
  border: solid;
}
```

```html
<div>Text</div>
```